# HIVE SQL - Create table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

While creating table using script, do i need to follow the order ?

```
    hive (testdb)> create table test(id int,name string,age int)
                > row format delimited
                > lines terminated by '\n'
                > fields terminated by ','
                > stored as textfile;
FAILED: ParseException line 4:0 missing EOF at 'fields' near ''\n''
```

The above query is causing and returning the error. see the same script just i reorder the lined and fields.

```
hive (testdb)> create table test(id int,name string,age int)
                > row format delimited
                > fields terminated by ','
                > lines terminated by '\n'
                > stored as textfile;
OK
Time taken: 0.175 seconds '
```

Any idea why first query is causing the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The Hive DDL is available on the wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTable)

Order does matter. `FIELDS TERMINATED BY` comes before `LINES TERMINATED BY`

```
row_format
  : DELIMITED [FIELDS TERMINATED BY char [ESCAPED BY char]] [COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY char]
        [MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY char] [LINES TERMINATED BY char]
        [NULL DEFINED AS char]   -- (Note: Available in Hive 0.13 and later)
  | SERDE serde_name [WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (property_name=property_value, property_name=property_value, ...)]
```

By default, tables stored as text already use newline terminators